# where to put compiled typescript files in angular 2 production app?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular

following this application structure in angular 2.
[angular app structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEd45.png)

If I put the compiled .js and .map files in the same directory as typescript file it becomes more cluttered structure.
so, where should I place the compiled js files (*.js) and map (*.js.map) files?

Comment: This question is off-topic for Stack Overflow for a variety of reasons.  First, it is too broad, since it's actually three questions in one.  Second, it is heavily opinion based.  And third, it could be seen as asking for external resources.  Down the road, please try to stick to concrete questions about specific workflow/code problems.  You'll get a much better response.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. :) I revisited my problem and cut it off into a single question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> where should I place the compiled js files (.js) and map (.js.map) files?

You can git ignore these `.js` / `.js.map` files and they will not clutter your git history and stuff (and your IDE might support hiding them as well).

That said you are free to use the `outDir` option to move the generated assets into a seperate directory